# JavaFX - изменение текста в treeview

Tags: java, javafx, button, treeview

Есть дерево с какими-то элементами. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку было можно изменить текст в выбранной ячейке. Но в интернете не могу нагуглить, как это реализовать... Я используй scene builder, для работай с fxml.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, для начала создай `Controller`, затем подключи есть к `fxml` файлу. Это можно сделать вот так: `fx:controller="путь к классу"`.
Затем следует создать поле у контроллера с таким же типом и названием, как и твоя кнопка.
 Не забудь строчкой выше прописать `@FXML`. 
Теперь в `scene builder` придумай и пропиши имя функции, которую надо будет реализовать. Прописывать ее следует в поле под названием `On Action`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее этот метод следует реализовать. Вот так:

```
public void secondButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEven) {

        Именно здесь и выполняются все команды. 
        Создаешь таким же образом и объект своего дерева. Дальше уже записываешь в него все что хочешь.

    }
```